# Custom listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I have created a custom listview using adapter. Each row of the list view contains profile image , textview and 5 imageviews. When I clicked on a particular item in the list, I need to display a view with 5 buttons. This new view should come just between the selected row and the item after selection. The new view will have the same width as of listview.

Could any one please tell me how can I achieve the new small view?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in adavance.
pratheeja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adapting ExpandableListView? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html
http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/09/expandablelistview-on-android.html